# Keep two Pie Charts Side by Side

Tags: html, canvas, chart.js, pie-chart

I have below code where the two pie charts are showing top - down. Instead I need to show them side by side.

I have tried below approach but I fail to achieve so.

Can someone please help me know where I do wrong?

**Code**

```
<div id="contain">  
    <div id="canvas-holder" style="width:50%" class="col-xs-6">
        <canvas id="chart-area" width="400" height="450"  style="display: block; float:left;margin-left:2em">
        <!--<canvas id="chart-area-km" width="400" height="450" style="display: block; float:right;margin-left:2em">-->
    </canvas></div>
    <!-- <div style="width: 50%">
        <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    </div>-->
    <div id="canvas-holder-keymsg" style="width:50%" class="col-xs-6">
        <canvas id="chart-area-km" width="400" height="450" style="display: block; float:right;margin-left:2em">
    </canvas></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried CSS floats? One floated left and one right, perhaps?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Yes I tried floats not working. Can you please help?

Comment: Floats are there in the style

Comment: Try adding the float to the div that surrounds the canvas.

Answer (score 3):

I have put code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sooraj771989/vxLad53k/). Make proper use of floats for canvas-holder

```
 <div id="contain">
 <div id="canvas-holder" style="background-color:#ff3400;width:50%;float: right;" \
 class="col-xs-6">
 <canvas id="chart-area" width="400" height="450" \
 style=" float:left;margin-left:2em"></canvas></div>
 <div id="canvas-holder" style="background-color:#000;width:50%;float: right;" \
 class="col-xs-6">
 <canvas id="chart-area-km" width="400" height="450" \
 style="float:left;margin-left:2em"></canvas></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```
<div id="contain">  
    <div id="canvas-holder" style="float:left;">
        <canvas id="chart-area" width="400" height="450" style="background-color:#ff3400;"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="canvas-holder-keymsg" style="float:right;">
        <canvas id="chart-area-km" width="400" height="450" style="background-color:#289182;"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```